# dlopen failed: "libarchitect.so" is 64-bit instead of 32-bit

Tags: android, x86, arm

I am designing AR app using Wikitude.

Its working fine for few mobiles.

But few highend devices, app is getting crash. I checked this below mentioned issue also:

```
http://www.wikitude.com/developer/developer-forum/-/message_boards/message/786231?p_p_auth=9ofvVzVi
```

Suggest me if any possible approaches.

Answer (score 3):

Try building "libarchitect.so" for 32-bit architectures, because 32-bit libraries can work on 64-bit phones as well as 32-bit phones.

Comment: pardon, I am a beginner for this. Could you please explain me little more.

Comment: have you got solution for that?